# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://ell.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: **Finally**, it happened.

Answer (score 5):

We have about a half-dozen candidates running so far, but I was hoping there would be more people running than that.

If you think you have the qualities of a good moderator, if you spend time on ELL regularly, and if you think you could make ELL a better place, then I would encourage you to run. I was hoping we'd get enough candidates that voting would be a tough decision for everyone.

If the only thing holding you back is shyness, or a fear of failure, then throw your hat into the ring. The worst you can do is lose an election – but please don't let the community lose its chance to elect a capable moderator.

If you've been sitting on the fence, then go for it!

Comment: You've succeeded; it is already a tough decision.

Comment: I think it made it too tough - only 259 out of 1384 eligible voted ;) That's more than half of the 500 folks that visited the site though.

Comment: @ColleenV - FWIW, that participation rate roughly mirrors that of our [sister site, ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/election).